# SwiftUI component details

Tags: swift, swiftui

Does anyone know what view this is within SwiftUI?

This is within the Apple Maps app.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI doesn't directly expose a view that looks exactly like that. In fact those buttons are probably implemented using UIKit.

It doesn't take much code to implement your own buttons with a similar appearance:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct DevSemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button { 
                print("car button pressed")
            } label: { 
                Image(systemName: "car.fill")
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            }
            Divider()
            Button { 
                print("location button pressed")
            } label: { 
                Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            }
        }
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
        }
        .tint(Color(uiColor: .secondaryLabel))
        .frame(width: 44)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ZStack {
    Color.mint
    DevSemView()
})
```

Dark mode appearance:

[image: Two buttons stacked vertically, drawn to look like the buttons in Apple Maps in dark mode. The top bottom shows the car icon. The bottom icon shows the location icon.]

Light mode appearance:

[image: Two buttons stacked vertically, drawn to look like the buttons in Apple Maps in light mode. The top bottom shows the car icon. The bottom icon shows the location icon.]

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Thanks for helping out and letting me know about UIKit also, will look into it now.